# Tracking a File or a document using web API

Tags: c#, .net, file-watcher

Wanted to ask a open question about tracking a file

we are trying to implement a system where we can track and monitor documents as they move around or are e-mailed or circulated over intranet.

This is what we are thinking of doing (assuming everything is all secure)

1. user will use a UI to to upload a confidential doc.
2. We will add a tracker to the document which is not available to the user
3. provide the user with the document with the tracker
4. When user circulates it to someone. we will use the tracker to call a server which is setup to invoke a web api call and update database with that user and document details
5. based on the data collected, we will see if it was shared appropriately or not

We have SQL server at the backend and WEB API2 for our service operations.

**My question is about the various strategies we can use for the tracker??? 
we are not getting any ideas there and will appreciate any help in that area**

All we want to do is that when user open that document..it invokes something...and makes a API call..and we save some information

Comment: Feels too broad for SO. Search term "IRM" (information rights management) may help you with your research.

Comment: we have decided to use an old 1x1 old image obfuscation strategy to insert a image with a pingback server url and using ASPOSE to change the property of the uploaded files. whenever someone opens a file it pings back the server and we get notified about the details of the activator.

Answer (score 0):

When I start to think about solution the only idea which came to me is to ONLY allow open documents in browser in web editor on your page. Why? Because take a look on `txt` file: any editor will work, moreover it doesn't allow to attach custom code.

In office files situation is better by all macros are blocked by default, so your API won't be executed if user does not decided to notify you